# How to count the number of items to be provided in Dynamic dropdown of RibbonX using lastrow in VBA rather than giving constant value?

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I have 2 dropdown in Excel customUI. 1st dropdown counts the number of items using *.End(xlUp)* while in 2nd dropdown number of items is directly given as 5 ie *returnedVal2 = 5*.The first dropdown ***Getitemcount1*** gives me error while using *.End(xlUp)* formula. But in second dropdown as *returnedVal2=5* is directly written so there is no error. What is the cause of the error here ?

```
Sub GetItemCount1(control1 As IRibbonControl, temp As Long, ByRef returnedVal1)
 Dim varItems As Long
varItems = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) - 3
returnedVal1 = varItems
End Sub

Sub GetItemLabel1(control1 As IRibbonControl, index1 As Integer, ByRef returnedVal1)
returnedVal1 = Sheet1.Cells(index1 + 4, "A").Value
End Sub

Sub GetItemCount2(control2 As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal2)
returnedVal2 = 5
End Sub

Sub GetItemLabel2(control2 As IRibbonControl, index2 As Integer, ByRef returnedVal2)
returnedVal2 = Sheet1.Cells(index2 + 4, "B").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)`   is a cell resp. a range  and `varItems = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) - 3` will return the value of the cell and you subtract 3 which will not work in case the content of `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)` is a text. You probably want the row number which is `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

**PS** It would be helpful if you said more about the error. Just stating *gives me error* is not helpful. You probably get a run time error 13 but that is just a guess.